# Cut timestamps in file

Tags: linux

I am stuck up with cutting timestamps in the beginning from /var/log/messages.
I need the output of all lines from /var/log/messages cutting timestamps in the beginning.
I did this:

```
cut -d " " -f4-30 /var/log/messages
```

[image]

but first lines still have the timestamps. I don't know how to use my cut command in proper way to have a result without timestamps.

Comment: Sample of the file please and a clear indication of what you want as output.

Comment: this file is messages in /var/log/ directory and it is very big.

Comment: I want to cut timestamps in the beginning of file 'messages' in /var/log directory. But after using command above it gave me the output with timestamps at the beginning. Second part of cutting output has normal result with cutting timestamps.

Comment: That command (or better `cut -d ' ' -f 4- /var/log/messages`) should work. Are you sure it's a space character and not a tab one or other form of spacing character that you have in-between those `"` characters?

Comment: I have never worked with message log in var directory, so I think it is a space character. I find out that in some places there are two spaces between Oct and 11  - maybe it's the core of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you asked for `cut`, but, IMO, `awk` is so much more robust here:

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' /var/log/messages
```

This skips the first three columns and prints the rest.

`awk` is way more robust since its default field separator is **one or more space or tab characters**. `cut` is limited to a single character, hence your issue, I think.